# Why does CreateWindowEx intermittently fail in Fall Creators Update (error 998 / 0x3e6)?

Tags: winapi, mfc, windows-10

After updating Windows 10 to the Fall Creators Update, I'm experiencing intermittent failures in `CreateWindowEx`.  `GetLastError` returns 0x000003e6 -- ERROR_NOACCESS / invalid access to memory.  Frequently (though not always), simply repeating the call with the exact same parameters succeeds.

```
hwnd = ::CreateWindowEx(0, wndClassName, NULL, WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_CLIPCHILDREN | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS,   r.left, r.top, r.right, r.bottom, hParent, NULL, AfxGetInstanceHandle(), NULL);
```

`wndClassName` is name of `wndClass` registered with this call:

```
LPCSTR wndClassName = /* clsName passed in */;
WNDCLASS wndcls;
HINSTANCE hInst = AfxGetInstanceHandle();
if (!(::GetClassInfo(hInst, wndClassName, &wndcls)))
{
    ZeroMemory(&wndcls, sizeof(wndcls));
    wndcls.lpfnWndProc = ::DefWindowProc;
    wndcls.hCursor = ::LoadCursor(nullptr, IDC_ARROW);
    wndcls.hInstance = hInst;
    wndcls.lpszClassName = wndClassName;
    wndcls.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)::GetStockObject(NULL_BRUSH);
    AfxRegisterClass(&wndcls);
}
```

MSDN documentation states that one of the typical reasons for failure is

> The WH_CBT hook is installed and returns a failure code

My application does use MFC and I believe MFC relies on a CBT hook.

Any ideas on how to investigate and resolve these persistent, intermittent failures that started occurring with Fall Creators Update?

Comment: need debug code. only this is way. I not think that CBT hook here play role. error code say for self - you try access or invalid address or bad aligned data in window procedure. need look are it called at all, if yes - which messages it got.

Comment: @RbMm window procedure is DefWindowProc -- added window class registration call to question.

Comment: and you not change it (`DefWindowProc`) later to own ? what sense have custom window class with `DefWindowProc` ? in any case error say for self. look like you got `STATUS_DATATYPE_MISALIGNMENT` or may be (less possibility I be say until `STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION`)

Comment: @RbMm We subclass it later after other things happen: SetWindowLongPtrW(hWnd, GWLP_WNDPROC, (INT_PTR) AfxGetAfxWndProc());  In your experience, does `STATUS_DATATYPE_MISALIGNMENT` go away by simply repeating the call with the same parameters?

Comment: `STATUS_DATATYPE_MISALIGNMENT` if you use some misaligned data/structure. in some case this can be. if you allocate this structure during window creation but not special align it. so it can be random or aligned or not. very hard say which is happens without debugging. you need begin from window proc - are it called at all for this window on fail ? this is question #1

Comment: @RbMm unfortunately, it takes about a half hour and several hundred windows before `CreateWindowEx` fails -- I can't repro on demand.  I'll work on automating a fail case.

Comment: nasty error. this kind of fail very hard research

Comment: MFC does indeed set up a CBT hook before window creation, to attach the `CWnd`(-derived) instance to the window handle prior to the first message being passed to the window procedure. I don't know whether this is related to the error, though.

Comment: The Creators Updates seem to be a way to add random bugs to Windows for no obvious benefit to anyone.

Comment: Why can't you use `CWnd::Create/CWnd::CreateEx`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a Windows 10 Fall Creators Update bug that was fixed in [Win10 FCU Update KB4054517](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4054517/windows-10-update-kb4054517) released December 12.

The bug affected 32-bit large address aware applications running on 64-bit versions of Windows 10 Fall Creators Update.  CreateWindowEx failed when enough memory below 0x80000000 was not available to the kernel.

For documentary purposes, these are the actions we took to get insight into the problem:

1. open a technical support request at http://support.microsoft.com/oas
2. get shuffled around until ending up in engineering technical support
3. have case assigned to the author of a blog post about [troubleshooting CreateWindowEx failures](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dsui_team/2012/11/05/troubleshooting-createwindowex-failures/)
4. spend days trying to produce steps to repro the failures so that the problem can be inspected in the kernel debugger
5. fail to get case that can repro
6. another customer was able to send in a repro case that has similar CreateWindowEx failures with same error code (problem with 32-bit application running on 64-bit version of Win10 Fall Creators Update).
7. cross fingers and wait for possible fix in December Patch Tuesday

Comment: Here's the official known issue from MS: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4054150/issues-when-windows-10-fall-creators-update-calls-createwindowex